# Seekbar want to save progress

Tags: android

I am using seek bar i want to save changes made by user in seekbar & should be shown next time whenever he will open app . My code is

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start=-10;      //you need to give starting value of SeekBar 
    end=10;         //you need to give end value of SeekBar 
        start_pos=5;    //you need to give starting position value of SeekBar 

        start_position=(int) (((start_pos-start)/(end-start))*100); 
        discrete=start_pos; 
        SeekBar seek=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); 
        seek.setProgress(start_position); 
        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){ 

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "discrete = "+String.valueOf(discrete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            } 
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

            } 
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                // To convert it as discrete value 
                float temp=progress; 
                float dis=end-start; 
                discrete=(start+((temp/100)*dis)); 

            } 
        }); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/1616443) - and try to understand how to save data in preference. 
Then in your Activity

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
 // save seekBarPgrogress to preference here.
}    

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
// load seekBarPgrogress from preference here.
// and call seek.setProgress(position);
}
```

Hope its help

Answer (score 0):

Save seekbar progress to shared preference in onPause and set seekbar progress from shared preference in onResume